# how to check entered date should be greater than system date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, function, user-defined-functions

heres the problem, i pass a date to function in the following format: mm/dd/yyyy.
when i pass the date as 02/02/2010 to the function it always returns true but i have put the condition that if date is less than system date it should return false but still it returns true for dates entered less than system date.heres the function.

```
Private Function expiryvalidate(ByVal exp As String) As Boolean
    Dim ee As String
    ee = Format(CDate(exp), "MM/dd/yyyy")
    Dim dd As String = Format(DateTime.Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
    If ee <> "0" Then

        If ee < dd Or ee = dd Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True

        End If
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I agree with the two answers you got; in any case, bear in mind that what you claim is not reflected in your code at all. If you input exp = "02/02/2010" the condition If ee < dd Or ee = dd Then is true (and False is returned). You should do some debugging to confirm that the input conditions are the ones you expect.

Comment: @varocarbas : i did debugging..both the dates format are the same..but still it doesnt work.

Comment: It works with me (VS 2010, .NET 4.0). In any case, as said, you shouldn't be dealing with dates as strings.

Comment: @varocarbas yes dear...now when i am dealing it as date its working fine..well strings and dates are not made for each other :D

Comment: Please, read my comments: YOU HAVE TO TREAT DATES AS DATES (no buts, no discussion; otherwise you are coding wrongly). BUT I tested your code (dealing with strings) and it works fine.

Comment: @varocarbas.. sorry for that(yes dear)..yup i will keep in mind(treating dates as dates)..thank you for guiding me for the right way of coding...

Comment: See... yesterday (actually, starting this weekend) and today I am dealing with really crazy, nonsensical persons I don't know where came from (never seen such a idiots in SO in the last 5 months). The common feature to all these idiots is wanting to misunderstand, not getting any idea, etc. Sorry if I have acted a bit aggressively but seriously I am speechless: I wouldn't ever expect to having to deal with such "people" in SO, a place I respected a lot until a short time ago. Sorry again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41961/discussion-between-vimal-vasudevan-and-varocarbas)

Comment: if you absolutely want to use string then you should overwrite the culture info of your program when its tarts to a culture that have MM/dd/yyyy. then when you get the date as string it will always have the format as per the culture you enforced. English US and English Canadian should be fine.

Comment: @Franck you were the one advising to use DoEvents in a previous question, don't you? Don't you see that there are already two valid answers? And that your suggestion is, at least, misleading: why are you suggesting to "overwrite"?, you mean passing the given culture as argument for the given function? Overwrite might be misunderstood as changing the default culture in the given computer what would be something pretty disadvisable (or better: stupid).

Comment: @varocarbas Effectively you are a victim of a serial downvoter, but don't worry, worse for him. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: @Steve thanks for the support. I am not worried, just feeling curious. And looking for justice (cowards and idiots have to know that they are cowards and idiots and be treated as such (to make from the world a better place and stuff); I don't like fanatismus at all :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could pass the date as a `Date` type then it is simply as this:

```
Private Function expiryvalidate(ByVal myDate As Date) As Boolean
    Return myDate < Today
End Function
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It will return true if the passed date as argument is less than the current system date, otherwise it will return false.

If you need to pass the date as string to the function then you can call it as this:

```
dim IsExpired as boolean = expiryvalidate(date.parse("mystringdate"))
```

Comment: hi i modified your code and added this which now works If exp > Today Or exp <> Today Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If

Comment: @vimal vasudevan you are checking wrong the conditions, you are cheking if the date is greater and also if is different, but if date is different then you can asume that the date is less or greater than today, in essence is different, after adding your last condition your expression is checking this: `if exp is greater or is lower than date...` so you only need to perform one condition: `Return exp <> Today` and remove the `if exp > date...` PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: But the OP was claiming something wrong, his original code (, although formally horrible, ) was working fine.

Comment: @elektrostudios i actually need to check whether the date is less than or equal to the current date..if it is less than or equal to current date then it should return false...otherwise true

Answer (score 1):

Comparing two strings pretending that they should be treated as dates cannot end well in any case.

You should convert the input string to a date and then compare against `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Today`. In this way the compiler knows how to compare correctly the values that represents the date without having any problem with the actual Display Format of the dates

```
Private Function expiryvalidate(ByVal exp As String) As Boolean
    Dim ee As DateTime
    Dim culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
    Dim DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
    if DateTime.TryParse(exp, culture, styles, out ee ) Then
        if ee <= DateTime.Now Then
           Return True
        else
           Return False
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Of course, this will be useless if you have already a datetime to check.
In that case the check could be done inline without any need to call a function

```
if currentDate <= DateTime.Now Then 
   ......
```

Comment: thank you steve..well i used ElektroStudios answer with my own modification..well i had to pass that as an date argument so now it works.

Comment: But the OP was claiming something wrong, his original code (, although formally horrible, ) was working fine.

Comment: @varocarbas, no I think that the original code cannot work correctly. What if today is 6 October 2013 and the date passed as test is 6 September 2014?. (Should be accepted, but September (09) is lower than October (10) and the string comparison fails)

Comment: Don't misunderstand me, please: the original code was horrible, shouldn't ever be used, no discussion on that. BUT the OP was complaining about a very specific situation, which I did test and which effectively works under his conditions. The reason for my comment was saying: look at your inputs because you might be getting different values than what you think (and change the code to treat dates and they should be treaten, no discussion on that).

Comment: (I am getting a bit surprised during the last days; this batch of downvoters is just the last stage)... but you seriously think that someone with my ranking (in both VB.NET and C#) would ever consider to deal with dates as strings? Even before seeing my answers, just with global numbers.. I don't know.. perhaps I am the one provoking misunderstandings but I am not sure why I have to explain some things... no problem with you Steve, just that I took advantage from this question to highlight something I am seeing lately (really surprising to me): having prejudices but in the "wrong direction" :)

Comment: Well, the world is full of different people thinking in different ways. I am no more surprised when I see certain behaviors (and believe me, as Italian, I have seen things that other humans still have to see:)), but I digress here. Yes, now I see what do you mean with 'was working fine' See you again on SO.

Comment: (LOL) Bear in mind that Italy and Spain are half brothers. See you around.